# Как отличить JSON от $_POST

Tags: php

Как отличить JSON запрос от POST(тот который $_POST['Значение']) ? Например если приходит JSON то делать одно действие, а если пост то делать с ним другое.

Comment: Заголовок `Content-Type` запроса смотреть, вестимо.

Comment: А если придёт POST с JSON?

Comment: не проще все данные в json тулить?

Comment: @DanielProtopopov не придёт. Только одно из двух

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Смотря что Вы конкретно хотите, если Вы принимаете на сервер JSON запрос, например через curl, то так

```
if (isset($_POST)) {
// прилетел пост

    if (isJson($_POST['Значение'])) {
       // а может прилетел json в посте
    }
} elseif ($json_str = file_get_contents('php://input')) {
    // возможно прилетел json
    if (isJson($json_str)) {
       // точно прилетел json
    }
}

function isJson($string) {
     json_decode($string, true);
     return json_last_error() == JSON_ERROR_NONE;
    }
```