# Как считать на сервере (php) имя POST запроса отправленного из Android приложения

Tags: php, java, android

Всем добрый день, отправляю из приложения Android POST запрос с json

```
 OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
    String json = getJson();
    RequestBody body = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("application/json; charset=utf-8"), json);
    Request request = new Request.Builder()
            .url(getUrl())
            .post(body)
            .build();
    Response response = client.newCall(request).execute();
    return String responseString = response.body().string();
```

на стороне сервера php следующий скрипт

```
<?php
$test = $_POST['Определить имя этого запроса'];
?>
```

Как определить В php скрипте имя POST запроса ?

Comment: Что выводит var_dump($_POST) ?

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/774666/186083

Comment: @RaZik
Ответ на var_dump($_POST)

`<pre class='xdebug-var-dump' dir='ltr'>
<b>array</b> <i>(size=0)</i>
  <i><font color='#888a85'>empty</font></i>
</pre>`

Comment: @Visman Спасибо, разобрался

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В коде скрипта вставил

```
if (isset($_POST)) {
// прилетел пост

    if (isJson($_POST['Значение'])) {
       // а может прилетел json в посте
    }
} elseif ($json_str = file_get_contents('php://input')) {
    // возможно прилетел json
    if (isJson($json_str)) {
       // точно прилетел json
    }
}

function isJson($string) {
     json_decode($string, true);
     return json_last_error() == JSON_ERROR_NONE;
    }
```

[Источник ответа](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/774663/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-json-%D0%BE%D1%82-post/774666#774666/)